# AJAX JSON Parser error PHP

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Here is my code. I keep getting a json parser error. The ajax never goes into done. Help!

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="load"/>
<div id="wines">
    <!-- Javascript will print data in here when we have finished the page -->    
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');

    $('.button').click(function(){ // This event fires when a button is clicked
        var button = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
            url: baseUrl, // JQuery loads serverside.php
            data: 'action=' + $(this).val(), // Send value of the clicked button
            dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
        }).done(function(data) { // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
            console.log("j");      
        }).fail(function(data,error) { 
            console.log(error);  
       })
    });
});
```

```php
<?php
    $action = req('action');
    // Red wine table
    $red = array('Chianti', 'Barolo', 'Pinot Noir');
    $white = array('Chardonnay', 'Cava', 'Chablis');

    // Combine red and white tables into one multidimensional table

    $winetable = array(
      "red" => $red,
      "white" => $white,
    );

    // Finally depending on the button value, JSON encode our winetable and print it
    if ($action == "load") {
          print json_encode($red);
          header('Content-Type: application/json');
    }
?>
```

UPDATE:
Error message shows this in the console:

```
"Initializing System Events for WUH..." common_admin.js:22
"["Chianti","Barolo","Pinot Noir"]
<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="load"/>
<div id="wines">
  <!-- Javascript will print data in here when we have finished the page -->
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var $ = jQuery;
    var baseUrl = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');

  $('.button').click(function(){ // This event fires when a button is clicked
    var button = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
      url: baseUrl, // JQuery loads serverside.php
      data: 'action=' + $(this).val(), // Send value of the clicked button
      dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
    })
    .done(function(data) { // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
      console.log("j");      
    })
    .fail(function(data,error) { 
      console.log(data.responseText+error);  
     })
  });
});
</script>parsererror"
```

Comment: What is the exact response of the request? You can check it in the network tab of the console. Also note that your PHP code never sets the `$action` variable, so it will never enter your `if` statement

Comment: I dont think you need that header at the end

Comment: In the response, there is SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 5 of the JSON data.

Comment: You cannot send headers after output

Comment: I removed the headers. While there is no SyntaxError in the response, it still goes to the ajax fail.

Comment: can you show us exactly what console.log(error); outputs?

Comment: It shows ""parsererror""

Comment: where is method req,  $action = req('action');, sho then conditional to print response will not work?

Comment: The json_encode string shows in the response, so the $action gets the value needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should print your headers BEFORE sending any body, else you may encounter classical headers errors:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (...)

For this you should move your `headers()` call BEFORE `print json_encode(...)`, like this:

```php
// Finally depending on the button value, JSON encode our winetable and print it
if ($action == "load") {
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      print json_encode($red);
}
```

Next, as you might have other instructions runned after printing your JSON, you should, as @PranavBhaat said, add a `die` or `exit` statement at the end of your script so you're sure nothing else is outputted and the JSON is correctly parsed by your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to end-up your ajax response call with `exit();`

```
if ($action == "load") {
          echo json_encode($red);
          exit(); 
}
```

and print will let you formatted output which not required, I think.

so just echo also been working.